# ¿Cómo crear columna de tipo datetime a partir de tres columnas con el año, dia de la semana y hora?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, funcion

¿Cómo puedo crear una función para convertir las columnas año, dia de la semana y hora en datatime y obtener una salida como la de la imagen de abajo?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Función para convertir año, día de la semana y hora en datetime
def convert_to_datetime(df):
    return

# Aplicar la función
passengers_per_hour_day['datetime'] = passengers_per_hour_day.apply(convert_to_datetime, axis=1)

passengers_per_hour_day.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
passengers_per_hour_day.tail()
```

Comment: Hola Luis, falta "la imagen de abajo" ;). Aparte de eso, podrías agregar un ejemplo del dataframe del que partes y el tipo de las columnas implicadas y si has intentado algo para resolverlo? La primera duda que me surge es que para tener los datos necesarios para generar un dato datetime nos faltaría el mes y el dia, porque el dia de la semana  es irrelevante.